# Flash not writing to socket correctly

Tags: c, sockets, flash, actionscript

I have a simple socket server written in C:

```
read_fds = master;
select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

for(i = 0; i<= fdmax; i++)
{
    if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds))
    {
        if (i == listen_fd)  //new connection
        {
            newfd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);

            if (newfd != -1)
            {
                int val;
                fprintf(stderr, "New connection!");

                if(-1 == ioctl(newfd, FIONBIO, (val =1, &val)))
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "second bad meme");
                }

                FD_SET(newfd, &master);

                if (newfd > fdmax) {
                    fdmax = newfd;
                }
            }
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "hello");
            nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
            if(nbytes <= 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Dead");
                close(i);
                FD_CLR(i, &master);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I connect to it using flash like this (I run it within flash, so policies should not be an issue at this point):

```
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.allowDomain("*");

var socket = new XMLSocket;

socket.connect("12.34.56.78", 8080);

socket.onConnect = function(success) {
    if(success) {
        trace("connected");
        var result = socket.writeUTF("sent from client\n");
    }
}
```

When I start my server, then start the flash file, I see "New connection!" on the server, and flash also reports it has connected.

I would then expect to see "hello" come out at the server (the fprintf in my C code) followed by "sent from client". However nothing happens.

If I close the flash file, I *do* see "hello" followed by "Dead". So it seems like `socket.writeUTF() is not working, or I just don't properly understand how to write to a socket using flash.

I have a packet monitor installed, and I can see that flash is trying to send something to the IP of the server, but I don't know why it's not working.

Either way it seems as if the problem is on the *client* side. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: You probably need to flush the socket on the client side after having written to it: `socket.flush();` Also closing the socket might do, will say flushes the buffer implicitily.

Comment: I tried adding socket.flush after the write, no difference.